# Is there a way to make a temp table in Snowflake via SQL without having to write the columns in everytime? WITH, INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
insert into temp
select  code, 
case when code = 'S' then 1
when code = 'U' then 0
when code = 'R' then 4 
end 
from "table" r
```

temp table error-how do you make a temp table in snowflake without having to note each column

Answer (score 1):

```
Create temp table temp as
select  code, 
case when code = 'S' then 1
when code = 'U' then 0
when code = 'R' then 4 
end 
from "table" r;
```

Comment: getting this error for that error: SQL compilation error: Object '"table"' does not exist or not authorized. I am using Snowflake.

Comment: Do you actually have a table called "table" in your database?

Comment: no, do I have to create a dummy table for this? Is there a way to do via with () or insert into without specifying all the cols and data types?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify the columns of the target temp table matching to the list of columns list in the select statement.

Yes, you have to specify all column name including data types.

```
create table "table" ( code varchar);

insert into "table" values ('S');
insert into "table" values ('U');
insert into "table" values ('R');

select  code, 
case when code = 'S' then 1
when code = 'U' then 0
when code = 'R' then 4 
end 
from "table" r;

Create temp table temp as
select  code, 
case when code = 'S' then 1
when code = 'U' then 0
when code = 'R' then 4 
end 
from "table" r; --SQL compilation error: Missing column specification


Create temp table temp (code varchar, code_no int) as
select  code, 
case when code = 'S' then 1
when code = 'U' then 0
when code = 'R' then 4 
end as code_no
from "table" r;

select * from temp;
```

Document Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#optional-parameters

Comment: What if there is 40 cols and you don't want to specify each col ? Is there a way just added a temp table without specifying each col? Also, I got this error: SQL compilation error: Object '"table"' does not exist or not authorized. I am using Snowflake.

Comment: Yes, you have to specify all column name including data types.

Comment: Edited my above answer to add more details

Comment: I see to create the table with cols and datatypes and then add in the data. Is there a way to do via with () or insert into without specifying all the cols and data types?

Comment: This will work without the column names.  I named the column in the case statement.

Create temp table temp as
select  code, 
case when code = 'S' then 1
when code = 'U' then 0
when code = 'R' then 4 
end as code_no  
from "table" r;